# Grails: how to generate a human-friendly for-sure-unique random number

Tags: grails, random, unique

I have a domain class which will have many children.  Related to this other post of mine: [Grails: how to structure transactions when I want to continue validating even after the transaction has already failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204723/grails-how-to-structure-transactions-when-i-want-to-continue-validating-even-af)  I want to create an instance of the parent class (MikeyJob), but NOT save it.  Then make a bunch of children, and only if the children validate, save the parent and all the children.

This is all fine and good, but `MikeyJob` 's need a job number and this number must be unique.  This is confusing me because there will be lots of "maybe it will get saved" `MikeyJob`s floating around in different sessions.

This is my thought:

```
import java.util.Random
Class MikeyJob{
  BigInteger jobNumber

  def beforeInsert() = {
    //this is where I think I need help
    Random rand = new Random()
    BigInteger max = 99999999
    BigInteger randomInt = rand.nextInt(max)
    MikeyJob.withSession{
      while(randomInt<9999999 || MikeyJob.findByJobNumber(randomInt)){
       randomInt = rand.nextInt(max)
      }
    }
    this.jobNumber = randomInt
  }

  static hasMany=[jobItems:JobItem]
  static constraints = {
    jobNumber(nullable:true)
  }
}

Class JobItem{
  String importantStuff
}
```

So I have a service that basically goes like this:

```
Class JobMakerService{
  def makeAJob(def bigMessyList){
    def someNewJob = new MikeyJob()  /NOT SAVED
    def validItems = []
    def invalidItems = []
    bigMessyList.each{
      def jobItem = //pseudo code to get a job item out of messy list
      //also not saved
      if(jobItem.validate())validItems.add jobItem
      else invalidItems.add jobItem


    }
    if(invalidItems = []){
      someNewJob.save()
      validItems.each{
        it.save()
      }
    } else def errorHandling  = 1/0


  }
}
```

This seems to be working, but is there a better way?

Comment: Are you restricted to using `int`s? Or can you use strings for the `jobNumber`?

Comment: Preferably it would be an 8 digit number.

Comment: It needs to be reasonably human accessible.

Comment: Okay. Normally I'd say that a [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) would do well if A) you can allow strings, B) the size doesn't matter, and C) it's not visible to end-users.

Answer (score 1):

Does it really need to be random?  Or just unique?  Getting a "random" number can't really guarantee that it is unique across everything or even across time.

First thought that comes to mind is to have a singleton type object that just adds 1 to the previous number (or use a database sequence).  Don't set it until you are truly trying to save the whole tree.  Your singleton could seed itself with the largest persisted job number + 1.

I have also used just a timestamp string, can make sure it is unique by adding a session unique value.  ie.. user_id + "-" + new Date().time

EDIT:

Beans declared in Spring (grails) are Singletons by default (one instance for the container, not the Singleton Pattern.)  So every time you autowire / inject a bean, it is the same instance throughout the system.  Then you throw a synchronized method to get the next value in there.  You can wire the bean up to grab it's seed (starting value) from the largest persisted (assigned) value from the database when the container starts up.

Using a database sequence is a bit different, as it relies on the underlying database to assign the value, but it would do the same thing.  You should be able to define the field in the domain object to auto assign the value given by a sequence.

Look at http://mycodesnippets.com/2010/03/30/sequence-generation-with-gorm/  But for your scenario, you would want the generator on your jobNumber field.  (Not 100% sure that will work though, never tried on any field except id)

Comment: Hrmmmm... these words like "singleton" and "database sequence" look like things I should know about...